# Spark-Submit: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {10.0.0.5, 10.0.0.4}:9042

Tags: scala, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to submit the job using command

> "spark-submit --class it.polimi.dice.spark.WordCount --master yarn-master --conf spark.cassandra.connection.host=10.0.0.5 --num-executors 1 --deploy-mode client --driver-memory 512m --executor-memory 512m  /home/useruser/temp/spark-cassandra-example/target/scala-2.10/spark-cassandra-exmaple-assembly-1.0.jar"

But I am getting error although I have tried the same thing using spark-shell and it is working it means that version of the spark-Cassandra connector **1.6.0-M1(spark version is 1.6.0 , scala 2.10.5, cassandra 3.3.0)** and other configurations are fine. Here is the result I am getting after using spark-submit command.

```
16/11/21 09:39:03 INFO Client: Application report for application_1479668866076_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/11/21 09:39:04 INFO Client: Application report for application_1479668866076_0014 (state: ACCEPTED)
16/11/21 09:39:05 INFO YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: ApplicationMaster registered as NettyRpcEndpointRef(null)
16/11/21 09:39:05 INFO YarnClientSchedulerBackend: Add WebUI Filter. org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter, Map(PROXY_HOSTS -> sandbox.hortonworks.com, PROXY_URI_BASES -> http://sandbox.hortonworks.com:8088/proxy/application_1479668866076_0014), /proxy/application_1479668866076_0014
16/11/21 09:39:05 INFO JettyUtils: Adding filter: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.webproxy.amfilter.AmIpFilter
16/11/21 09:39:05 INFO Client: Application report for application_1479668866076_0014 (state: RUNNING)


16/11/23 10:10:38 INFO NettyUtil: Found Netty's native epoll transport in the classpath, using it
16/11/23 10:10:38 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.0.0.4:9042 added
16/11/23 10:10:38 INFO Cluster: New Cassandra host /10.0.0.5:9042 added
16/11/23 10:10:38 INFO CassandraConnector: Connected to Cassandra cluster: Test Cluster
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO SparkContext: Starting job: fold at WordCount.scala:17
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (fold at WordCount.scala:17) with 2 output partitions
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (fold at WordCount.scala:17)
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List()
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List()
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (CassandraTableScanRDD[1] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15), which has no missing parents
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 7.1 KB, free 7.1 KB)
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 3.7 KB, free 10.9 KB)
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on 10.0.0.6:58236 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 143.6 MB)
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO SparkContext: Created broadcast 0 from broadcast at DAGScheduler.scala:1006
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting 2 missing tasks from ResultStage 0 (CassandraTableScanRDD[1] at RDD at CassandraRDD.scala:15)
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO YarnScheduler: Adding task set 0.0 with 2 tasks
16/11/23 10:10:39 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, sandbox.hortonworks.com, partition 0,RACK_LOCAL, 29218 bytes)
16/11/23 10:10:40 INFO BlockManagerInfo: Added broadcast_0_piece0 in memory on sandbox.hortonworks.com:51013 (size: 3.7 KB, free: 143.6 MB)
16/11/23 10:10:43 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1, sandbox.hortonworks.com, partition 1,RACK_LOCAL, 29156 bytes)
16/11/23 10:10:43 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0, sandbox.hortonworks.com): java.io.IOException: Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {10.0.0.4, 10.0.0.5}:9042

16/11/23 10:10:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, sandbox.hortonworks.com, partition 0,RACK_LOCAL, 29218 bytes)
16/11/23 10:10:45 INFO TaskSetManager: Lost task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1) on executor sandbox.hortonworks.com: java.io.IOException (Failed to open native connection to Cassandra at {10.0.0.4, 10.0.0.5}:9042) [duplicate 1]
```

Can anyone kindly help me ho wi can fix this issue.

Comment: He Safia, welcome at stackoverflow. It is good to review the formatting of your post. It potentially deters people, who might be able to answer it for you E.g.. For code you can use 4 spaces before each line to make it stand out. You can also use the wysiwyg editor.

Comment: Oh never mind, someone just did the editing :)